# RxJava if/else with multiple chain calls

Tags: android, filter, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I have a webservice call that return an object in which there is a parameter that indicates whether the operation ended successfully or not, so I would like to filter it (kind of if/else statement) inside the `RxJava` chain by using RxJava operators. Is it possible?

Something like this but not using if/else:

```
    repo.webserviceCall(username, password)
            .flatMap(result -> {

                if (result.isSuccessful())
                    repo.secondWebserviceCall(result.getInfo())
                else
                    showToastMessage("Api call not successful"); //STOP FLOW HERE

            })
            .flatMap(result -> thirdWebserviceCall(res))
            .subscribe(res -> {showSuccessMssg(res)}, throwable -> { showError(t)});
```

Comment: What is the return type of the `webserviceCall`?

Answer (score 1):

You can return an `error()` from your flatMap so that the execution then goes to the `onError` consumer in your subscribe call.

Comment: but I want to avoid using if/else statement

Comment: asking about a way to avoid using them

Answer (score 1):

If each service call returns one item, you could rearrange the operators so that not successful won't run the flatMap for the second and third calls. The filter will turn the setup to empty for which you can use the `onComplete` handler to display the toast.

```java
repo.webserviceCall(username, password)
.filter(result -> result.isSuccessful())
.flatMap(result ->
    repo.secondWebserviceCall(result.getInfo())
    .flatMap(result -> thirdWebserviceCall(res))
)
.subscribe(
    res -> showSuccessMssg(res),
    throwable -> showError(t),
    () -> showToastMessage("Api call not successful")
);
```